# Docker Django Application not serving project static files but serves public static

Tags: django, docker, nginx, django-staticfiles

I cannot get my site to serve my projects "base.html" template or any other project level files.

It successfully serves items from the public directory and any content from the apps directory.

However nothing from my "BASE_DIR".

I am running this site in a docker container just internally.

The django-admin loads perfectly with all its css.

**settings.py**

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

path.append(BASE_DIR)

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)

path.append(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "apps"))
path.append(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "libs"))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'public/media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'public/static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'
            ],
        },
    },
```

]

[image]

**project/apps/app/templates/home.html**

not extending base

```
{% templatetag openblock %} extends 'base.html' {% templatetag closeblock %}
{% templatetag openblock %} block content {% templatetag closeblock %}
    <p>Welcome, start editing  test this template in <code>apps/base/templates/base/home.html</code></p>
{% templatetag openblock %} endblock {% templatetag closeblock %}
```

Comment: have you tried to set `DEBUG=True` in settings ?

Comment: yes i am running my container in debug

Comment: can you explain the error message ?